# What does "Linked" mean?

Tags: java, collections

Lots of classes in Java are prefixed with the "Linked" identifier, i.e. `LinkedList`, `LinkedBlockingQueue`, `LinkedHashmap`, etc. What does the term "linked" mean?

Comment: See [Linked list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linked_list).

Comment: @Jesper thanks! So, a "Linked" collection is a collection whose members are each - sort of - aware of the proceeding member?

Comment: Yes, and it's not Java-specific, it's a general data structure design principle, most programming languages have linked lists in their standard library.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A Java `LinkedList`, is a `List` implementation that uses [linked lists](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linked_list). In contrast, one could also implement them using for instance [dynamic arrays](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_array), which is what `ArrayList` does.

A `LinkedBlockingQueue` follows much the same idea as a `LinkedList`.

A `LinkedHashMap`, is a normal [hash table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table) (which provides efficient random access), combined with a [doubly-linked list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doubly_linked_list) (which provides consistent iteration order).

Thus, the `Linked` prefix means, that a linked structure (such as singly- or doubly-linked lists) are a key part of their underlying implementation.

Answer (score 2):

Here, the term "linked" means that each member of the collection is aware of the next member in the collection via a "link"; therefore, each member can be stored in a non-sequential location in memory.

The above, very simple contribution is derived from the [Linked List](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linked_list) Wikipedia article mentioned in a comment made on the original question.

Answer (score 1):

There are some Collection in java which starts with `Link`. Regardless what is followed by `Link` there is some common property of these collections -

**1.** These collections are always ordered

**2.** Can insert element at any position. For example you can insert item at a `LinkdeList`.

**3.** mantains a link to connect with the next/previous item where each item is called node. You ma consider a simplified version of node like this -

```
class Node{
  int value;
  Node next;
  Node previous;
}
```

Here `Node next` and `Node previous` works as a link to the next/previous node from the current node.

Comment: - All lists (array based and list based) are ordered    
- All lists (array based and list based) allow inserts via the add(int index, E element) method